# Program will only output else statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, stdin

I'm working on creating a linear search in Java using the StdIn library from Princeton, and I can't figure out why my `if-else` statement will only print out “-1”.

It seems to me that its skipping over the `if` block entirely and going straight onto the `else`. I'm entering in my list with command-line arguments and ending the list by pressing control-d (not sure what it is on windows, sorry). Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class SearchAlgs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args[0].equals("linear")) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            LinearSearch(n);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter linear");
        }
   }

   public static void LinearSearch(int n) {
       int x = -1;
       //int u = -1;
       int c, search, array[];
       int value = StdIn.readInt(); //input values
       array = new int[value]; //array list

       while (x < 0) {
           //System.out.println(n);
           //System.out.println("linear");

           //loop to populate array list
           for(c = 0; c < value; c++)
              array[c] = StdIn.readInt();  


           //loop to search for "n"
           for (c = 0; c < value; c++) {
               if(array[c] == n){
                   System.out.println(n + " is at index " + c);
                   x++;
                   return;
               }
               else{
                   continue;
               }
           }

            System.out.println("-1");
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I updated the entire `LinearSearch(n)` method. It now finds the value from the list that I enter and gives me the value of `-1` when the value is not there. The problem now is that the `ArrayList` only populates to whatever the first number I enter is when I need to populate to however many `int`s are entered in the command-line argument

Comment: Use a debugger to find it out

Comment: @Jens How would I do that? Sorry, I'm very new to programming in general

Comment: use google to find out how you can do it

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @SteveSmith I'm using DrJava

Comment: http://drjava.org/docs/user/ch09.html

Comment: What did you mean by StdIn?

Comment: which else part is executing?

Comment: The second else part, the one that is inside the for loop @HirenJungi

Comment: @Cosmics StdIn is a library created by library created by Princeton that is like Javas standard input/output library. [Here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) is where I got it

Comment: how many and what arguments you are providing at command line?

Comment: @HirenJungi They're ints and I'm providing however many I want, anywhere from 2-500+, it just depends on what the input is

Comment: without knowing the input it's difficult to know what is causing the errors.

Comment: @HirenJungi The input is entered by the user when you load the file in command line. After you compile you'd enter "java LinearSearch 4" with 4 being the value that it is looking for. It would then run and have the user enter in the int values until they do control-d (not sure for windows). The problem now is that it will only let you enter in whatever number you first enter, say I entered 1 as the first value then I would only be able to have 1 number in my array list but if I entered 4 I would be able to enter 4 values. The problem is I need it to be infinate

Comment: i have done your search please check the code it is working fine;

Answer (score 1):

Your method will return (after printing -1) as soon as the searched value is not in the array:

```
    else{
        System.out.println("-1");
        return;  // EXITING HERE
    }
```

so if the value entered is not the the first value in the array, you will get -1 and the method is terminated.

What you probably want is to return (after printing) as soon as the value IS FOUND, or continue searching up to the last array entry. After this loop exists, that is, nothing was found, you want to print -1 (and return/terminate).

Something like

```
loop array {
    if value is equal array entry {
        print message
        return
    }
    // else continue looping
}
print -1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, isn't that pretty much what I have with the second for loop that contains my if else statement?

Comment: sure not - your return is in the ELSE, mine is in the IF. your print -1 is inside the loop, mine is AFTER the loop.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. I did what you suggested yet I'm still getting -1 no matter where I put the integer I'm looking for. Do you think it would be easier to use a while loop? Something such as while(array[c] != n) then put the if statement after that?

Comment: strange, it is working fine for me... kind of two changes: move the -1 part outside the loop, add a return to the if part. I, personally would prefer the FOR solution, but should be not much different than a while

Comment: I will update my original code to show what my loop looks like now. Thanks for all the help

Comment: well, the changed code is working fine for me, now the problem could be the data being read (or not). For testing I implemented a (reduced) version of StdIn.

Comment: I have updated the code to what you suggested and have almost everything working except what I added in my edit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of effort I have completed your code.

Run program as follows java SearchAlgs 4 5 6 7

> enter size:5
>
> 67546

Output would be :

> 6 is at index 2
>   7 is at index 3
>   5 is at index 1
>   4 is at index 0

Code:
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class SearchAlgs {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[]=new int[(args.length)-1];
        int conv=0;
        if (args[0].equals("linear")){
            for(int i=0;i<(args.length-1);i++)
            {
                conv=Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
                list[i]=conv;
            }
            LinearSearch(list);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter linear");
        }
   }


public static void LinearSearch(int n[]){
    int x = -1;
    int c, search, array[];
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
    System.out.print("Enter size:");
    int size = reader.nextInt();
    array = new int[size]; //array list

   while (x < 0){
       //loop to populate array list
           for(c = 0; c < size; c++)
              array[c] = reader.nextInt();  

       //loop to search for "n"
       for (c = 0; c < n.length; c++){
            for(int z=0; z<n.length;z++){
               if(array[c] == n[z]){
                   System.out.println(n[z] + " is at index " + z);
                   x++;
               }
               else{
                   continue;
               }
           }
       }
         x++;

   }
}
}
```